# Strange behavior on very large numbers

Tags: big-numbers

I want to test the value of a differential equation by replacing a solution and setting random values for r and z variables:

```
sol = ψ -> Function[{r, z}, Sinh[2 (r + z)^2] + Tan[4/3 + r] + 5 (-r + Tanh[1/r])];

de2 = 1/(4*r^2) - D[ψ[r, z], z]^2 + D[ψ[r, z], z, z] + D[ψ[r, z], r]/(2 r)+ D[ψ[r, z], r]^2 +  D[ψ[r, z], r, r];
```

If I set for example:

```
N[de2 /. sol /. r -> -9 /. z -> 4]==0
```

I get a false result. The value is a very large negative number (-3.16913*10^29).

If I set:

```
N[de2 /. sol /. r -> -90 /. z -> 4]
```

I get 0.*10^12836 in red, and a message saying "No significant digits are available to display."

If I compare this last command to zero:

```
N[de2 /. sol /. r -> -90 /. z -> 4]==0
```

I get True! What's happening? How could I prevent this from occurring?

Not using PZQ because it is too slow for the number of tests I want to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are large numbers and you need to increase [`$MaxExtraPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MaxExtraPrecision.html), as well as 
use non-machine arithmetic. E.g.:

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 8000;
N[de2 /. sol /. r -> -90 /. z -> 4, 20]
```

gives

```
1.4495694130768246652*10^6429
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
N[Expand[de2 /. sol /. r -> -90 /. z -> 4]]
```